# Pass files to PHP through Ajax (no redirect)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I've been trying to pass an image from ajax to PHP from a file upload in the form.

The following is my ajax call:

```
var dataString = 'city='+ city_push + '&venue=' + venue_push + '&title=' + title_push + '&subtitle=' + subtitle_push + '&date=' + date_push + '&time=' + time_push + '&price=' + price_push + '&description=' + description_push + '&tag1=' + tag1_push + '&tag2=' + tag2_push + '&email=' + email_push + '&newvenue=' + newvenue + '&password=' + password_push;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "assets/new.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        alert("success");
      }
    });
    return false;
```

I want to add to my dataString the file so I can process it in the PHP file with $_FILES. Is there a way to do this and maintain the current structure? This ajax code is being called on a successful form submit.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So from what I gather, there is no way to do this? @sphanley the solution to that one doesn't seem to work (maybe only works in FF)

Comment: Javascript is not allowed to directly access the file system of the machine on which it's running, so no, without using a form to submit it there's no only-Javascript way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of string, you should look into using an object.  JavaScript has a `FormData` object that you can `append` items to.  Append all your data and then you can `append` your image file like this...

```
var formData = new FormData();
// add your variable values here using the append method
// Ex: formData.append('key', value);
var imageFile = document.getElementById('yourfileuploadidhere').files[0];
formData.append('image', imageFile);
```

You'd want to do some type checking on the client end to catch invalid formats and then validate it on the backend as well. 
Once your `formData` object is complete, just use `data: formData,` in your ajax call.

Comment: How would you then get it in the PHP? Would it be $_FILES['image']? Thanks again! I'm a complete noob at ajax, literally started learning last week.

Comment: yes.  and the other metadata would exist in the `$_POST` array.  `$_POST['city']; $_POST['venue'];` etc where you add each key>value to your `formData`.